# google ebooks from linux to ereader

Tags: nook, google-play-books, linux, acsm

I am considering a ereader (nook) where I can read my ebooks downloaded from google-play books.

Only problem is when I download `.epub` from Google Play Store, I actually get an `.acsm` file, not `.epub`, and Google Help says I need Adobe Digital Editions (ADE) to convert.

I can probably do that with wine + ADE, but I don't think I can transfer it to nook as wine do not support USB (as far as my last experience and I haven't use wine for years).

Given this scenario, is there any other way to get Google e-books on my nook?

NB: I haven't bought my ereader yet, just exploring; but one of the criteria is to be able to read Google books in my ereader and do it within linux.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 3):

For Linux you need to run ADE in Wine. [On this page there is a pdf and a video](http://www.westlakelibrary.org/http://www.westlakelibrary.org/?q=taxonomy/term/634) that I made for my library on using ebooks via ADE for Linux users. FWIW, I had trouble getting ADE to detect ereaders on Linux ( ubuntu). Your mileage may vary. Good hunting!

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Digital Editions (ADE) is necessary for you to read e-books that have Digital Rights Management (DRM) attached.

After installing ADE, you will be prompted to login with or to create an Adobe ID, but don't worry, it's free.